# Is there any difference between "as if to check" and "as if she's checking" in the context?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, difference, sentence-choice

She starts whistling into his ear as if to check whether he really is dead.

She starts whistling into his ear as if she's checking whether he really is dead.

1. Is there any difference these?
2. Does "as if to check" refer to her and why she's whistling into his ear or is it more used to mean "as one does to check"?
3. Could I use "if" instead of "whether" in both sentences without changing the meaning?
4. Which one is the better option do you think?

Answer (score -1):

*To check* and *checking* both carry the same sense of an action, you could use either. *As if to check* is the usual phrase, *as if [she's] checking* has more of a sense that you're narrating events as they happen, because of that continuous form. It's a style thing, really.

The phrase is *as if*, *as whether* doesn't really work in the same way (you'll see those two words together in sentences, but as part of a completely different construction). You can use *as though* instead, that works (but not for the exclamation, *as if!* which means "that's not true, how ridiculous!")

Comment: This is wrong and misleading. "I am checking" is very different from "I am going to check".

Comment: The question's example is *as if to check* vs *as if checking*, I'm not covering every possible usage of the -ing form here!